# Joining curve surfaces

Tags: cad

I had used Creo Parametric to simulate loading of a section of an airplane wing. Look at the pictures below.

[image]

And there was a problem to join a skin to the frame of the wing in my assembly. Because frame elements are flat and skin is curve.

[image]

Maybe I'm not enough experienced user? - Well, I would be grateful for **any advice about use of Creo**. But personally I found Creo very inconvenient to deal with curve surfaces like airfoils because:

- In real life that's a peace of cake to join a flat plate to any curve surface - seems that in Creo it is merely impossible.
- Creo catches all the microscopic clearances between surfaces and that makes Creo to fail when generating mesh.
- Creo refuses to make holes on a curve surface wherever I wish.

**Could you suggest me some CAE software where there's no stuff like that and curve surface processing is easy?**

Comment: It is hard to asses your competence level. Yes and no software more suitabe does exist but if you expect to be able to use one with no investment of knowing how to use it. Complex modeling is never easy regardless of tool. Sounds like you want to use the freeform mode instead. You can chase your goal for a long time, you see no application particulary cares how you think it ought to work, they have no capacity for thinking. Because its more conductive to educate you on the tool you dont know very well, than to educate you on a tool you do not know at all. Care to explain your exact problem.

Comment: Ok. One of the possible solutions would be possibility to edit mesh manually (connect parts meshes with my own elements). As i know Femap of HyperMesh provide such feature. But I'm looking for something little bit more user friendly.

Comment: Problem is that meshes can not be booleaned effectively. Which is why CAD applications use a interdiction of using parametric surfaces. Still i wouldnt rule out there is a easy way to do what you want in creo, you just dont know all the tricks of thinking. I mean the hardest surface i had to make took me a month to builds the tools for, so just because you cant find a immediate way of dong X does not mean X is hard.

Comment: You can use a spinal bend on the Part, by making piece flexible you can apply different bends to different instances. But the cad is just a model, how much effort do you actually need to use?